# Minimise $C(x,y)=11x+3y$ subject to the constraints.

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Minimise $C(x,y)=11x+3y$ subject to the constraints $ g(x,y)=-3x^2-3y^2+10xy $ and $x\geq 0, y\geq 0$.
I started solving using this Lagrange multiplier, but the constraint set is not compact, right? So, how can I argue whether the critical point is a maximum or a minimum or a saddle point?

Answer (score 0):

What is your constraint on g(x,y)? There should be some equality or inequality, associated with that equation.